# How to get the values from json object which is in the form Future<String>?

Tags: json, string, flutter, dart, future

I am using aws_ai plugin and the response is in the form of 
`instance of Future<String>`

I read the response as given below. I need to access specific value from json with key "confidence", how do I access it?

```
Future main1() async {

  File sourceImagefile; //load source image in this File object
  String  accessKey = "",
          secretKey = "",
          region    = "" ;

  RekognitionHandler rekognition = new RekognitionHandler(accessKey, secretKey, region);
  if(sourceImagefile !=null && targetImagefile !=null) {
      Future<String> labelsArray = rekognition.compareFaces(
          sourceImagefile, targetImagefile);
      print(labelsArray);
      return labelsArray.toString();
    }else{
    return "Enter Image";}

}
___________________________________
(later in widget build:)
___________________________________
onpressed(){
main1().then((labelsArray){
    print("json value is:  "+labelsArray);
  });
}
```

the current result is :

`json value is: Instance of 'Future<String>'`

thanks for the help!

Comment: can you provide more detailed code.

Comment: sure I edited the question

Comment: take a look at the answer that should solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `Instance of 'Future<String>'` as a result is you are not waiting for the future to return and just getting the `Future<String>` object back [refer this](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures) for more details:

The below code should solve your problem:

```
Future<String> futureFunction() async {
    RekognitionHandler rekognition = new RekognitionHandler(accessKey, secretKey, region);
        if(sourceImagefile !=null && targetImagefile !=null) {
          var labelsArray = await rekognition.compareFaces(
              sourceImagefile, targetImagefile);
          print(labelsArray);

          return labelsArray.toString();
        } else {
            return "enter image";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. is this code for retrieving the response correct? ```futureFunction().then((val){
    print("json is: "+val);
  });

Comment: yeah, It could be the time it takes for it to recognize the image

Comment: Thanks for the response. is this code for retrieving the response correct? ```futureFunction().then((val){ print("json is: "+val); });

Comment: Yeah, you can use that